# Non XAML way to databind to collection/dictionary

Tags: wpf, dictionary, mvvm, data-binding

I have a requirement to dynamically load a diagram (XAML which includes custom UserControl, `ScrewControl`).

I am looking at the ways to bind the dependency property (`Status`) of `ScrewControl` from the ViewModel class. The Challenge is that a diagram could contain a varied number of `ScrewControl`s, each of which needed to be data bound to a dictionary or collection in a `ViewModel`.

I have solved the first challenge of loading the XAML dynamically using `XamlReader` but not sure how to bind `ScrewControl`s with Collection/dictionary from ViewModel.

View Model Class

```
public class AssemblyViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, ScrewStatus> Screws { get; set; }
    public FrameworkElement Image { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

View Class

```
public partial class AssemblyView : UserControl
{
    private AssemblyViewModel viewModel;

    public AssemblyView(AssemblyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    public FrameworkElement XamlContent
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(XamlContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XamlContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XamlContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("XamlContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(AssemblyView), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnXamlChanged));

    private static void OnXamlChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var view = dependencyObject as AssemblyView;
        var element = args.NewValue as FrameworkElement;
        if (null != element)
        {
            view.ContentControl.Children.RemoveRange(0, 1);
            view.ContentControl.Children.Add(element);

            var screws = element.FindChildren<Screw>();

            try
            {
                foreach (var screw in screws)
                {
                    // The ScrewControl has a name properties like "Screw_1", 1 is used as the key of the dictionary and Status as the Value
                    var parts = screw.Name.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (2 == parts.Length)
                    {
                        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                            screw,
                            Screw.ScrewStatusProperty,
                            new Binding(/*not sure what goes here*/)
                            {
                                Source = view.viewModel.Screws,
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // This works and loads the diagram 
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            this,
            XamlContentProperty,
            new Binding("Image")
            {
                Source = this.viewModel
            });
    }
```

Comment: To be able to answer this we need to see a minimal version of both the Xaml and the ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. This should work:

```
foreach (var screw in screws)
{
    // The ScrewControl has a name properties like "Screw_1", 1 is used as the key of the dictionary and Status as the Value
    var parts = screw.Name.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (2 == parts.Length)
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            screw,
            Screw.ScrewStatusProperty,
            new Binding() // No need for a path as we're going to bind directly to the source value 
            {
                // The source of the databinding is the value of the Screws dictionary keyed by screw id (parsed from the screw name)
                Source = view.viewModel.Screws[(int)parts[1]],
            });
    }
}
```

Although it might be more WPF'y to Screw controls loaded from the XAML a public property and bind it as the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl. You could then set the ItemTemplate to be a ContentControl with the Content property bound to the ScrewStatus and the ContentTemplate bound to the current item (i.e. the screw user control loaded from XAML) which would provide a more natural way to bind the view and model together.